# HTTP Status 404 - /pages/show.jsp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, struts2

I have create a project using Struts2.
It is working perfectly in my `localhost`, but after uploading it to server it is showing `HTTP Status 404 - /pages/show.jsp`. The same problem I'm facing for many pages that is only after uploading war file to the server. Many times I have deleted war file and uploaded it again, but  the same problem remains.

I am using Apache Tomcat 8 at server.
What may be the reason how to resolve this?

I have included a file in JSP with `<jsp:include page="/pages/show.jsp"/>`
My `pom.xml` is http://pastebin.com/MHpaLEmf.
Error log is http://pastebin.com/NsgLe9RK

Comment: Is the WAR file completely exploded? If not, try to also delete the exploded directory after uploading and before starting.

Comment: @RomanC Yes It is working I am using maven

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose How to Check??

Comment: please see it here http://pastebin.com/MHpaLEmf

Comment: I have included files in jsp like    `<jsp:include page="/pages/show.jsp"/>`

Comment: Your error log is full of `java.net.BindException: Address already in use`. Your tomcat isn't starting properly.

Comment: Try reinstalling Tomcat. It's the fastest thing

Comment: Also use 2.3.24.1, not 2.3.16

Comment: @AndreaLigios Yes it is working . Thank you You resolved my problem. Any thing else need to change/ to do

Comment: @AleksandrM working properly

Comment: And now you've wasted a bounty :( the bounty points won't come back if unassinged, they will just get lost :/ I suggest @AleksandrM to answer since he noticed startup problems as first.

Comment: Ok no problem. Thanks alot for finding the appropriate probem. Without bounty I was unable to get solution. I am happy that my problem get resolved:)

Comment: Sorry Yesterday It was not allowing me to accept bounty not I am assigning it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Tomcat logs shows numerous `java.net.BindException: Address already in use` exceptions. That means that port which Tomcat uses is already used by some other application. Change ports in Tomcat configuration or shutdown application that currently uses these ports.

Answer (score 2):

You  need to set base Url have a look at this example

```
    <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<c:set var="req" value="${pageContext.request}" />
<c:set var="url">${req.requestURL}</c:set>
<c:set var="uri" value="${req.requestURI}" />

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2204870</title>
        <base href="${fn:substring(url, 0, fn:length(url) - fn:length(uri))}${req.contextPath}/">
        <script src="js/global.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.jsp">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="faq.jsp">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.jsp">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: OP haven't provided any code. How do you know that base url isn't set?